# Outlook VBA - linked image in ReplyAll mailitem created from Custom from template not displaying

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, images, templates, outlook-form

The below code creates a mailitem from a custom Outlook Form Template and a ReplyAll mailitem and appends the ReplyAll mailitem to the Template mailitem. However, the image icon from the Outlook form template does not get displayed. Instead, inplace a Red cross (x) with a text placeholder having the below message displays :

[image]

`The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.`

```
Public sTempPath        As String
Public sCat             As String
Public Const sDefaultPath As String = "pathtotemplate"

Public Sub LoadReplyTemplatesForm()

  frm_ReplyTemplates.Show
  
End Sub


Sub ReplyWithTemplate(sTempPath As String, sCat As String)

Dim olItem              As mailItem
Dim olReplyAll          As mailItem
Dim olTemplateItem      As mailItem
Dim olCategories        As Categories
'Dim cid                 As String
'Dim objFSO              As Object
'Dim objTempFolder       As Object
'Dim objAttachment       As Object
'Dim sPath               As String
'Dim sFile               As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
' select active mail item
If TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
    Set olItem = Application.ActiveWindow.CurrentItem
Else
    Set olItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
End If

If olItem.Class = 43 Then   'olMail = 43
    Set olReplyAll = olItem.ReplyAll
    Set olTemplateItem = CreateItemFromTemplate(sTempPath, Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox))

    ' set selection object properties
    With olReplyAll
        .To = olItem.To
        .CC = olItem.CC
        .BCC = olItem.BCC
        
        ' check if category exists, if not, add it to Master list
        .Categories = olItem.Categories
        Set olCategories = Application.Session.Categories
        If Not InStr(1, olItem.Categories, sCat, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            olCategories.Add sCat, 20     'Dark Green
            On Error GoTo 0
            .Categories = .Categories & "," & sCat
        End If
        .FlagRequest = olItem.FlagRequest
        
'            .HTMLBody = olTemplateItem.HTMLBody ' Use the template's HTML body
            
'            ' Extract and re-embed image attachments from the original email
'            For Each objAttachment In olTemplateItem.Attachments
'                If objAttachment.Type = olByValue Then ' Check if the attachment is an embedded image
'                    cid = "cid:" & objAttachment.fileName ' Use the attachment's filename as the Content-ID (CID)
'
'                    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'                    Set objTempFolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
'                    sPath = objTempFolder.Path & "\"
'                    If InStr(1, olTemplateItem.HTMLBody, cid, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
'                        With objAttachment
'                            sFile = sPath & .fileName
'                            .SaveAsFile sFile
''                            .Attachments.Add sFile, , , .DisplayName
'                            .PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1"
'                            olTemplateItem.HTMLBody = Replace(olTemplateItem.HTMLBody, "cid", "cid:MyId1")
'                        End With
'                        objFSO.DeleteFile sFile
'
'                        ' Replace the original image link with the CID in the HTML body
''                        olTemplateItem.HTMLBody = Replace(olTemplateItem.HTMLBody, objAttachment.fileName, cid)
'                    End If
'                End If
'            Next objAttachment

            .HTMLBody = olTemplateItem.HTMLBody & .HTMLBody


'            ' Append the original email's HTML body
'            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><br>" & olReplyAll.HTMLBody

            ' adding team image logo from template
'            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'            Set objTempFolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
'            sPath = objTempFolder.Path & "\"
'            For Each objAttachment In olReplyAll.Attachments
'                With objAttachment
'                    sFile = sPath & .fileName
'                    .SaveAsFile sFile
'                    .Attachments.Add sFile, , , .DisplayName
'                End With
'                objFSO.DeleteFile sFile
'            Next objAttachment
'            .Save

            .Display
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a Mail item!"
    End If

Cleanup:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & _
    " Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
    " Error Source: " & Err.Source, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Clear
    Resume Cleanup
End Sub
```

As you can observe from the commented code, I have tried all sorts of manipulations to get the image icon displayed, without any success.

Any help most appreciated!

Comment: Is the file hosted on the net or locally?

Comment: No @BlindSpots . the oft files are placed in a Sharepoint folder with full access. But i have tried placing them in the my local systems Templates folder also. Same issue. In code, If i reverse the `With olReplyAll` with `With olTemplateItem`, then image icon from template shows, but all replyall images in email chain become placeholders and do not display.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, this issue occurs when the BlockHTTPimages registry value is set to 1 and the images in the email message have a source that points to a URL. Please refer to this article and try the solution:

[The Linked image cannot be displayed error in an Outlook email message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/the-linked-image-cannot-be-displayed-error?ic=comm_reply)

Comment: Hi @christy, I had already checked `BlockHTTPimages`. It does not exist in my registry editor.

Comment: Please try to manually create the path and value.

Comment: what did you mean by manually create the path and value?

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\policies\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common. If you cannot find any key, you just need to right click > new > Key.

Comment: tried your suggestion. did not work!

Comment: I added BlockHTTPimages = 0 to both the locations as mentioned in your shared link.

Comment: What about changing to another image?

Comment: kindly elaborate what you meant by changing to another image?

Comment: To confirm if the issue is related to the image you inserted.

Comment: no issue with the image.